# Clear Sitecore cache for an item from cache programmatically

Tags: caching, sitecore

I want to clear Sitecore cache for an item programmatically. I ran the code below. After that I tried to do a `web.GetItem()` on the deleted id and I still get a `null`. Any suggestions?

```cs
Database db = new Database("web");

if (ID.IsID(id))
{
    ID itemID = new ID(id);
    
    //clear data cache
    db.Caches.DataCache.RemoveItemInformation(itemID);
    
    //clear item cache
    db.Caches.ItemCache.RemoveItem(itemID);
    
    //clear standard values cache
    db.Caches.StandardValuesCache.RemoveKeysContaining(itemID.ToString());

    //remove path cache
    db.Caches.PathCache.RemoveKeysContaining(itemID.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you have missed the prefetch cache, here is how to get it:

```cs
private Cache GetPrefetchCache(Database database)
{
    foreach (var cache in global::Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.GetAllCaches())
    {
        if (cache.Name.Contains(string.Format("Prefetch data({0})", database.Name)))
        {
            return cache;
        }
    }
}
```

And the html cache also:

```cs
private void ClearAllHtmlCaches() 
{
    foreach (var info in Factory.GetSiteInfoList())
    {
        info.HtmlCache.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does GetPrefetchCache and ClearAllHtmlCaches here clears all the cache of the site or only based on itemID? As the requirement here is based on itemID